# Disable globbing in PHP exec()

Tags: php

I have a PHP script which calls another script in order to add IP addresses to a whitelist. I sometimes want to whitelist all addresses, in which case I have it call

```
exec("otherscript *.*.*.*", output, retval);
```

This worked fine, adding the string "*.*.*.*" to the whitelist until I happened to have another file in the directory of the php script that matched that pattern ("foo.1.tar.gz"), at which point the wildcards were expanded, and I ended up with the filename in my whitelist. Is there some way to disable globbing in php's exec? It isn't mentioned in the PHP docs as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[escapeshellarg](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) will make sure your string is safe for using as a shell argument. Globbing is probably not mentioned in the manual because it's up to the shell, and also differs between different shells.

```
$address = escapeshellarg('*.*.*.*');
exec("otherscript $address", $output, $retval);
```

Comment: Sure, but the manual makes no mention of *any* sort of a shell.

Comment: Ignacio, I stand corrected! :-) However, the manual do have a big, red warning message about using escapeshellarg.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the parameter should help:

```
exec("otherscript '*.*.*.*'", output, retval);
```

Comment: Also make sure your input string to otherscript is sanitized. This can lead to all sorts of security issues.

Comment: Looks like in the end this is what escapeshellarg does as well